# AngularJS local build works dist build crashes browser

Tags: angularjs

I'm afraid I don't have much to show and that's my issue. I have an angular app which works fine locally but crashes the browser when I deploy it. Used angularjs-generator to build it. The browser crashes when attempting to use the dist build. The biggest issue is that the JavaScript console doesn't show any errors before the browser crashes so I'm at a loss on how to debug this? I've confirmed everything is in the dist folder that should be.

If anyone has run into this or has suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Which browser does it crash? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Try removing some dependancies piece by piece and seeing what causes the crash.

Comment: It crashes all browsers

Comment: have been able to confirm I can run the dist folder from my local nginx server...alas still issues on redhat....still searching....

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea. For me the yeoman angular generator crashed when I tried to perform 'grunt test' on so I was thinking that the problem you have was related. For me the reason was that there were some dependencies missing namely :

```
npm install grunt-karma --save-dev
npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: in the end...the issue is with trying to serve this under a subdirectory on a server. Thanks for chiming in people!